# What is the different between DataFrame.select() and DataFrame.toDF() in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

It seems that they all return a new DataFrame

Source code:

```
def toDF(self, *cols):
    jdf = self._jdf.toDF(self._jseq(cols))
    return DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx)


def select(self, *cols):
    jdf = self._jdf.select(self._jcols(*cols))
    return DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is subtle.

If you for example convert an unnamed tuple `("Pete", 22)` to a DataFrame using `.toDF("name", "age")`, and you can also rename the dataframe by invoking the `toDF` method again. For example:

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(("Piter", 22), ("Gurbe", 27)))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[2] at parallelize at <console>:27

scala> val df = rdd.toDF("name", "age")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, age: int]

scala> df.show()
+-----+---+
| name|age|
+-----+---+
|Piter| 22|
|Gurbe| 27|
+-----+---+

scala> val df = rdd.toDF("person", "age")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [person: string, age: int]

scala> df.show()
+------+---+
|person|age|
+------+---+
| Piter| 22|
| Gurbe| 27|
+------+---+
```

Using the select you can select columns, which can be later used to project the table, or to save only the columns that you need:

```
scala> df.select("age").show()
+---+
|age|
+---+
| 22|
| 27|
+---+

scala> df.select("age").write.save("/tmp/ages.parquet")
Scaling row group sizes to 88.37% for 8 writers.
```

Hope this helps!